# user.FirstName in .cshtml.cs file is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using Identity in my .net core 6 MVC app and I'm trying to display the user's first name on a razor page, here is the .cshtml.cs file:

```
using CubeAuthAttempt1.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace CubeAuthAttempt1.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
    public class WorkModel : PageModel
    {

        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        //constructor 
        public WorkModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public void OnGet(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            ViewData["firstname"] = user.FirstName; 
        }
    }
}
```

.cshtml file:

```
@page
@model CubeAuthAttempt1.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage.WorkModel
@{
}


<div>
    <h2>Hello @ViewData["firstname"]</h2>
</div>
```

ApplicationUser.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CubeAuthAttempt1.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace CubeAuthAttempt1.Areas.Identity.Data;

// Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<Cart> Cart { get; set; }
}
```

When I debugged this to see what the value of the user.FirstName is I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZE93.png)

Thank you in advance, much appreciated.

Comment: It could simply caused by user is not login. Try do a if else statement to test user has login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters of `OnGet` method are used to pass values from the url. For example:

```
public class WorkModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet(int? id)
    {
    }
}
```

You need to go to this url to pass the id parameter the value 123

> http://localhost:{port}/Work?id=123

If you navigate to "http://localhost:{port}/Work" id parameter will be null.

So trying to pass the `ApplicationUser` as an `OnGet` parameter is wrong and it's null because we are not passing any query string parameters when requesting the Work page.

This is how you should do it:

```
public void OnGet()
{
    // holds identity information of the user who made the request, known as 'claims'
    var principal = User;

    // retrieve the ApplicationUser using UserManager
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
    
    ViewData["firstname"] = user.FirstName; 
}
```